# PresentationLink always use the same destination object

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I was surprised that whenever I tap on the button embedded in PresentationLink, the same view reference shows up all the time. What I mean is that we don't create another instance of the view.
This makes sense as the destination object is created within the body property and will therefore not be recreated unless a change occur.

Do you guys know if we have a trivial way to recreate a new view every time we hit the button? Or is it by design and should be use like this?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

After @dfd 's comment, it seems to be by designed.
Now how to handle this use case:

> Let's say I present a NavigationView and I pushed one view. If I
>   dismiss and re present, I will go back on the view I previously
>   pushed. In this case, I believe it's wrong as I'd like the user to go
>   through the complete flow every single time. How can I make sure that
>   I go back on the first screen everytime?

Thank you (again)!

**EDIT 2**

Here's some code:

```swift
struct PresenterExample : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PresentationLink(destination: CandidateCreateProfileJobView()) {
                Text("Present")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct StackFirstView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: StackSecondView()) {
            Text("Got to view 2")
        }
    }
}

struct StackSecondView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 2")
    }
}
```

In this case that would be `PresenterExample` presents `StackFirstView` which will push `StackSecondView` from the NavigationLink.
From there, let's say the user swipe down and therefore dismiss the presentation. When it clicks back on the `PresentationLink` in `PresenterExample` it will open back on `StackSecondView`, which is not what I want. I want to display `StackFirstView` again.

Makes more sense? :)

Comment: I believe it's by design. Is there a specific reason you wish to load a new instance of a view? If things are state-based it should reflect current content. While not as trivial as you may be looking for, just make *each* content component of your first destination object be it's own view and create a new destination view with a new name and include them. Remember, SwiftUI will automatically "flatten" each subview in a view into a single view, so it really won't cost you anything.

Comment: @dfd it's not a big problem most of the time except in this case: let's say I present a NavigationView and I pushed one view. If I dismiss and re present, I will go back on the view I previously pushed. In this case, I believe it's wrong as I'd like the user to go through the complete flow every single time. How can I make sure that I go back on the first screen everytime?

Comment: Show your code. Show two different views you'd like to present on two different occasions and the logic by which you choose between them. That will make it possible to advise on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So let me make sure I understand - two views (A and B) - are used by a `NavigationView`. A >> B >> A. Now, you want something else when navigating to B? (I'm hoping I'm not reading things right.) You aren't "pushing and dismissing and re-presenting", you are "pushing and popping and re-pushing". And if your model is properly updated, A and B... not matter what... should reflect the current state of the model. And yes, as @matt suggests, code would be helpful.

Comment: @dfd I just added some code with better explanation!

Comment: @matt I just added some code with better explanation!

Comment: I'm still learning this, so let's make sure I get this. `PresenterExample` is **presenting** (not pushing) `StackFirstView` that has a `NavigationController` to `StackSecondView`? And then you wish to (1) swipe down to dismiss the stack that contains both `StackViewOne` and `StackViewTwo`? and then (2) upon **presenting** (not pushing) from ``PresenterExample` you want `StackViewTwo`? That's not just not easy to do, it's not intuitive. Why not (a) use a `NavigationView` in a different way or (b) use a different navigation path?

Comment: No no, have another read, I want the excepted behavior. I want to see the first view anytime. You understood that I wanted to see view 2 when I re open which is what I DON’T want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First Try: Failure

I tried using the `id` modifier to tell SwiftUI to treat each presentation of `StackFirstView` as a completely new view unrelated to prior views:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PresenterExample : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PresentationLink("Present", destination:
                StackFirstView()
                    .onDisappear {
                        print("onDisappear")
                        self.presentationCount += 1
                }
            )
        }
    }

    @State private var presentationCount = 0
}

struct StackFirstView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: StackSecondView()) {
                Text("Go to view 2")
            }.navigationBarTitle("StackFirstView")
        }
    }
}

struct StackSecondView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 2")
            .navigationBarTitle("StackSecondView")
    }
}

import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: PresenterExample())
```

This **should** do the following:

- It should identify the `StackFirstView` by `presentationCount`. SwiftUI should consider each `StackFirstView` with a different identifier to be a completely different view. I've used this successfully with animated transitions.
- It should increment `presentationCount` when the `StackFirstView` is dismissed, so that the next `StackFirstView` gets a different identifier.

The problem is that SwiftUI never calls the `onDisappear` closure for the presented view or any of its subviews. I'm pretty sure this is a SwiftUI bug (as of Xcode 11 beta 3). I filed FB6687752.

### Second Try: <s>Failure</s>Success

Next I tried managing the presentation myself, using the `presentation(Modal?)` modifier, so I wouldn't need the `onDisappear` modifier:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PresenterExample : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Present") {
                self.presentModal()
            }.presentation(modal)
        }
    }

    @State private var shouldPresent = false
    @State private var presentationCount = 0

    private func presentModal() {
        presentationCount += 1
        shouldPresent = true
    }

    private var modal: Modal? {
        guard shouldPresent else { return nil }
        return Modal(StackFirstView().id(presentationCount), onDismiss: { self.shouldPresent = false })
    }
}

struct StackFirstView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: StackSecondView()) {
                Text("Go to view 2")
            }.navigationBarTitle("StackFirstView")
        }
    }
}

struct StackSecondView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 2")
    }
}

import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: PresenterExample())
```

This fails in a different way. The second and later presentations of `StackFirstView` simply present a blank view instead. Again, I'm pretty sure this is a SwiftUI bug. I filed FB6687804.

I tried passing the `presentationCount` down to `StackFirstView` and then applying the `.id(presentationCount)` modifier to the `NavigationView`'s content. That crashes the playground if the modal is dismissed and presented again while showing `StackSecondView`. I filed FB6687850.

#### Update

[This tweet from Ryan Ashcraft](https://mobile.twitter.com/ryanashcraft/status/1151148754507952129) showed me a workaround that gets this second attempt working. It wraps the `Modal`'s content in a `Group`, and applies the `id` modifier to the `Group`'s content:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PresenterExample : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Present") {
                self.presentModal()
            }.presentation(modal)
        }
    }

    @State private var shouldPresent = false
    @State private var presentationCount = 0

    private func presentModal() {
        presentationCount += 1
        shouldPresent = true
    }

    private var modal: Modal? {
        guard shouldPresent else { return nil }
        return Modal(Group { StackFirstView().id(presentationCount) }, onDismiss: { self.shouldPresent = false })
    }
}

struct StackFirstView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: StackSecondView()) {
                Text("Go to view 2")
            }.navigationBarTitle("StackFirstView")
        }
    }
}

struct StackSecondView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 2")
    }
}

import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: PresenterExample())
```

This revised second try successfully resets the state of the `Modal` on each presentation. Note that the `id` must be applied to the content of the `Group`, not to the `Group` itself, to work around the SwiftUI bug.

### Third Try: Success

I modified the second try so that, instead of using the `id` modifier, it wraps the `StackFirstView` inside a `ZStack` when `presentationCount` is an odd number.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PresenterExample : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Present") {
                self.presentModal()
            }.presentation(modal)
        }
    }

    @State private var shouldPresent = false
    @State private var presentationCount = 0

    private func presentModal() {
        presentationCount += 1
        shouldPresent = true
    }

    private var modal: Modal? {
        guard shouldPresent else { return nil }
        if presentationCount.isMultiple(of: 2) {
            return Modal(presentationContent, onDismiss: { self.shouldPresent = false })
        } else {
            return Modal(ZStack { presentationContent }, onDismiss: { self.shouldPresent = false })
        }
    }

    private var presentationContent: some View {
        StackFirstView()
    }
}

struct StackFirstView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: StackSecondView()) {
                Text("Go to view 2")
            }.navigationBarTitle("StackFirstView")
        }
    }
}

struct StackSecondView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 2")
    }
}

import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: PresenterExample())
```

This works. I guess SwiftUI sees that the modal's content is a different type each time (`StackFirstView` vs. `ZStack<StackFirstView>`) and that is sufficient to convince it that these are unrelated views, so it throws away the prior presented view instead of reusing it.

Comment: Oh thanks for digging into this. So that’s what I expected, no way to do this without modifying the state which will re generate the body and therefore create another instance...

Comment: You got a lot of bug-filing mileage out of this question! Very cool.